# iTerm2 not showing currently where it's running

Tags: terminal, iterm2

I just installed iTerm2 and it's no showing accurately where my computer is running, I want to change on where it's running so is accurate.

[image]

I want to get rid of *"on [cloud icon] (sa-east-1)"* because I'm not actually on AWS Cloud to show this information, and I want it to show the right location on where I'm at within my terminal.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the solution to my problem, it happened that on

`/Users/my-mac/.aws/.config`

there was a line setting AWS region 'sa-east-1' as default as shown below:

```
[default]
region=sa-east-1
```

I simply commented this line resulting in

```
[default]
#region=sa-east-1
```

and my problem was solved since region `sa-east-1` was not the default setting of my profile anymore.